# Write a javascript code to press space inside a text box field after typing text?

Tags: javascript

I need to write a javascript code to press the space key inside a text box after typing the text. How is it possible?

[image: sample text box]

Comment: What is the reason you need to "press the space key"? Are you trying to add an additional space at the end of the text? Are you trying to trigger a function? Something else?

Comment: So, do you want to press the space key to navigate to the next input box?

Comment: space key selects or adds the email to the box so that I can type next email and so on. here space key acts like enter key so I wanted to press space.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to dispatch a 'keypress' event to the input:

```
myInput.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keypress',{'key':' '}));
```

Docs on [dispatchEvent()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/dispatchEvent), [KeyboardEvent()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/KeyboardEvent), and [keypress (deprecated)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/keypress_event).