# How to trigger a keypress in an input via a mouse click in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a use case where I need to trigger a keypress event in an input field via touch/mouse click

I have tried numerous approaches from stackoverflow answers such as .trigger($.Event( however none appear to work.

I am able to get this "working" via changing the inputs "val". However, there are other events inside the framework that is in place which are activated off the keypress so I really need to simulate a keypress rather than append the "val".

Here is sample non-working code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      .numKey { padding:16px; }
    </style>
  </head>
<body>
  <form id="lf" method="post">
    <div><input id="username" class="username"  type="tel" maxLength="13"  autofocus="autofocus"/></div>
  </form>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var userinput = document.getElementsByClassName('username')[0];
    function triggerEvent(el, type, keyCode) {
      if ('createEvent' in document) {
        console.log(keyCode)
        // modern browsers, IE9+
        var e = document.createEvent('HTMLEvents');
        e.keyCode = keyCode;
        e.initEvent(type, false, true);
        el.dispatchEvent(e);
      } else {
        // IE 8
        var e = document.createEventObject();
        e.keyCode = keyCode;
        e.eventType = type;
        el.fireEvent('on'+e.eventType, e);
      }
    }

    $(function() {
      $('.numKey').on('click touchstart', function() {
        var char = $(this).text().charCodeAt(0);
        userinput.focus();
        triggerEvent(userinput, 'keydown', char); 
      });
    });
  </script>
  <table id="keypad">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="numKey">7</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="numKey">8</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="numKey">9</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/b8o0xqgs/7/

Please can someone advise what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried this method: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61234219/3113485

Comment: why are you adding eventlisteners to .numKey when you want to get the key pressed on the input. Also, what key in input do you want the event to trigger?  If all, then when we enter say 12 we are pressing two keys (1 and 2)

Answer (score 0):

I tested this code and verified that it will emit a 'keypress' event to the input:

```js
  const myInput = document.getElementById('username');

  function inputKeyPress () {
    const e = new KeyboardEvent('keypress');
    myInput.dispatchEvent(e);
  }

  myInput.addEventListener('keypress', e => {
    console.log('input received keypress:', e);
  });
```

A button press produces this on console:

> input received keypress: – {isTrusted: false, key: "", code: "", location: 0, ctrlKey: false, …}

Thus showing that the dispatched event is received by the input.

The original question states: "there are other events inside the framework that is in place which are activated off the keypress".

Not knowing the specifics of the framework, it's hard to tell how this 'keypress' event directed at the input will propagate. The [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/keypress_event) say that 'keypress' events bubble, so it should propagate up the DOM tree just fine. At least the method here shows that a 'keypress' event can be directed at the input, and the input can capture it.